# Get window scroll position on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get scroll position which I got with this :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
    console.log(scrollTop)
})
```

but when I need to use the output value for a script in a document ready : `$(document).ready(function(){` I don't get anything.

Any idea ?

Comment: Declare your `scrollTop` variable in the global scope, this will allow you to use it within any function.

Comment: What do you mean by 'global scope' ?

Comment: @LéoDurand 
```
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
$(window).on('scroll', function(){

    console.log(scrollTop)
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(scrollTop)
})
```
something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semicolons missing! Declare variable in the global scope for use in `document.ready`. It's also unnecessary to place `$(window).on('scroll'` outside `document.ready` because you will never scroll before the `DOM` will be loaded.

```
var scrollTop = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    });

    //use scrollTop here...
});
```

Comment: Thanks David, but by putting `console.log(scrollTop)` inside my document.ready I still don't have anything, is it normal ?

Comment: Hmm.. Post your code and screenshot of console please.

Comment: The `var scrollTop` can (and should, IMO) go inside the document ready, so long as all the functions that need to access it are within the document ready.  Also, why not take the opportunity to teach about [no-conflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) safe document ready, such as `jQuery(function($) { // safe to use $ here }`

Comment: I created a jsfiddle with your code : https://jsfiddle.net/Leshautsdurant/7cxroath/
The console stay at '0'.

Comment: Semicolon is missing! And you need to add `console.log` to `$(window).on('scroll'` otherwise `scrollTtop` will only be printed only when `DOM` will be loaded.. https://jsfiddle.net/Leshautsdurant/7cxroath/2/

Comment: It is useless to put `console.log` into `document.ready` because you will always get zero. `document.ready` starts only once once all elements are ready. Why you need to use `scrollTop` outside `$(window).on('scroll'`?

Comment: I use Tweenmax to display or not divs and use anchors as keys to fake pages. Thanks to you I can get the value and now I'm trying to use it in :   `TweenLite.to(window, 0, {scrollTo:+scrollTop,delay:0.8}) `because when I click to my home button which use '#' for index.html, the scroll goes all up which is not what I want but stay at the same current position.